# npm run webpack failing with Attempted import error: 'Breadcrumb' is not exported from '@progress/kendo-react-layout' (imported as 'Breadcrumb')

Tags: webpack, breadcrumbs, kendo-react-ui

I have weird problem, where I am able to npm run webpack without any errors in my local machine but it suddenly stopped working on our build server with below error
'Breadcrumbs'

npm run webpack failing with Attempted import error: 'Breadcrumb' is not exported from '@progress/kendo-react-layout' (imported as 'Breadcrumb').

[image: error snapshot]

Appreciate any help to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Issue happened as "For one of the kendo packages (@progress/kendo-react-charts), a new minor version was published recently by the package owners (v5.15.0 - 5 days ago). It was dependent on a specific version of @progress/kendo-react-layout for it to compile properly. Hence, our webpack build started failing since then.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@progress/kendo-react-charts/v/5.15.0
"

Could also resolve this issue by adding below lines after npm install before npm run webpack

npm install --save @progress/kendo-react-layout
npm install --save @progress/kendo-react-layout@latest

Better Resolution
To fix this issue, we have now modified our package json to upgrade only patch versions automatically for all the kendo packages. For this, we have replaced the cap (^) symbol with tilde (~) symbol in our package json file.